# Force angular to consider scope property "dirty"

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to force angular to re-render things bound to a property, even though the property has not changed value? e.g:

```
$scope.size = 1;

<div some-prop="size"></div>

$scope.$needsRender('size') // psuedocode
$scope.$apply(); // re-renders the <div>
```

Unfortunately I can't manage the property entirely in angular for performance reasons, which is why I need this "reset".

Comment: If the value doesn't change, but the output is supposed to change, you're performing a non-idempotent binding somewhere, which is a bad idea. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mnemosyn the dom node has been manipulated by something else. I want to force angular to re-render that section and restore it to what angular thinks it should be.. does that make sense? Obviously this shouldn't happen bad practice etc etc regardless I would like to know how to do this.

Comment: That sounds like you're looking for `$scope.$apply`? e.g. `someFunc(function(modifiedValue){ $scope.$apply(function() { $scope.someWatchedValue = modifiedValue; }); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular DOM beeing manipulated outside of angular is ugly. Well to say the truth, it's more than that. People doing this probably deserves to die. slowly. Painfully.

But anyway yes, it is possible.

Short answer : You can do this be forcing the execution of a scope's watcher to fire.

```
module.factory("scopeUtils", function($parse) {

    var scopeUtils = {

        /**
         * Apply watchers of given scope even if a digest progress is already in process on another level.
         * This will only do a one-time cycle of watchers, without cascade digest.
         *
         * Please note that this is (almost) a hack, behaviour may be hazardous so please use with caution.
         *
         * @param {Scope} scope : scope to apply watchers from.
         */
        applyWatchers : function(scope) {
            scopeUtils.traverseScopeTree(scope, function(scope) {
                var watchers = scope.$$watchers;
                if(!watchers) {
                    return;
                }
                var watcher;
                for(var i=0; i<watchers.length; i++) {
                    watcher = watchers[i];
                    var value = watcher.get(scope);
                    watcher.fn(value, value, scope);
                }
            });
        },

        traverseScopeTree : function(parentScope, traverseFn) {
            var next,
                current = parentScope,
                target = parentScope;
            do {
                traverseFn(current);

                if (!(next = (current.$$childHead ||
                    (current !== target && current.$$nextSibling)))) {
                    while(current !== target && !(next = current.$$nextSibling)) {
                        current = current.$parent;
                    }
                }
            } while((current = next));
        }

    };

    return scopeUtils;
});
```

Use it simply like that :

```
scopeUtils.applyWatchers(myScope);
```